# Отправка писем в цикле

Tags: email, php

Здравствуйте. Не могу понять, почему не работает такой цикл:

```
foreach($arr as $mail){
    $res=mail($mail,"Это может быть тема письма",$msg,$header);
    if($res) echo "OK"; else echo "Sorry..";
}
```

Выводит: `OKSorry..Sorry..Sorry..` и т.д. В чем здесь может быть ошибка?

**UPD:**

Хедеры такие:

```
$header="Content-Type: text/html; charset=windows-1251\n";
$header.= 'From: vasya@pupkin.ru '. "\r\n"
Msg: '<h1>Hello!</h1>',
$arr: $arr=array([0]=>'mike@doe.com', [1]=>'mike@doe.com', [2]=>'mike@doe.com')
```

Comment: Что в массиве $arr? Расставьте фигурные скобки в условиях. У экстрасенсов сегодня выходной

Comment: @Barton, в массиве `$arr` хранятся все `E-mail`-ы для рассылки. Впервые слышу, что фигурные скобки в условии обязательны ))
Еще вопросы?

Comment: А разве я упомянул, что фигурные скобки обязательны? С ними код более удобочитаем.

Comment: Какие хедеры отправляете? $msg?Все переменные в студию. Включая $arr чтоб мы могли у себя протестировать код с такими же параметрами

Comment: >Выводит: OKSorry..Sorry..Sorry.. и т.д. В чем здесь может быть ошибка?

Ошибка в $arr.

Comment: Вы проверяли, первое письмо точно отправляется?

Comment: @Vitalii Maslianok, да, проверял. Первое письио приходит.

Comment: @alex_90, попробуйте 2-мя последовательными строками из скрипта (без foreach) отправить два письма и если второе не пройдет, то **поменять их местами**. Что придет ?

И еще, log MTA посмотреть можете ?

Comment: Заранее прошу прощения, если это быдлокодие, но везде рекомендуют ловить описание ошибок отправки mail примерно так
     
    function ErrorHandler($number, $message, $file, $line, $vars){
        $log=@file_get_contents('my.log');
        file_put_contents('my.log', $log."\n".$number." ".$message);
    };
    set_error_handler("ErrorHandler", E_ALL);

Неплохо было бы увидеть, какие вылетают ошибки/нотификации.
UPD. Интересно, а что будет когда обработчик ошибки не найдет my.log? Спасет ли @ или будет рекурсия до переполнения стека... Жалко php не установлен, даже любопытно стало.

Comment: @avp, поняли где проблема, осталось найти ошибку. К сожалению не знаю где смотреть логи MTA.
@ReinRaus, вы можете подробнее написать что и куда подставлять. Я хочу отловить ошибку..

Comment: Может быть хостер пытается пресечь отпроавку спама, а Ваш тест выгядит именно так. Попробуйте отправлять на разные адреса немного разные сообщения.

Comment: @avp, пробовал менять сообщение и адрес -- эффект тот же самый. Скорее всего стоит какое-то ограничение на отправку писем, как сказал @ikoolik.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Написал письмо в службу тех поддержки.. Оказывается было ограничение на время между отправкой писем - 4 секунды.

[@ikoolik](/users/5777/ikoolik), вы оказались правы))

Answer (score 2):

Не вижу проблемы. Стало интересно, скопировал код, расставил скобки. запустил и вуаля - все работает. Попробовал на хостинге тоже без проблем. Вот код:

```
$arr=array('test1@mail.com','test2@mail.com');
$msg = '<h1>Hello!</h1>';
$header="Content-Type: text/html; charset=windows-1251\n";
$header.= 'From: vasya@pupkin.ru '. "\r\n";
foreach($arr as $mail){
    $res=mail($mail,"Это может быть тема письма",$msg,$header);
    if($res) {
        echo 'OK<br />';
    } else {
        echo 'Sorry..<br />';
    }
}
```

Comment: @Barton, в точности скопировал ваш код(поставил свои E-mail-ы) -- результат тот же. Отправляется только первое письмо...

Comment: Я тоже пробовал в денвере- все нормально уходит) Мне кажется, автор задал вопрос, потому что правильный код выполняется неправильно и это странно)

Comment: @alex_90, могу посоветовать попробовать на другой машине, а еще лучше на хостинге. По возможности протестируйте с реальными адресами.

Comment: Ну на хостинге все нормально уходит. 30 писем в лет ушло.

Comment: Нашел где собака зарыта!! Эта штука неправильно работает на бесплатном хостинге. (Осталось понять почему). На платном все нормально, на Денвере пока не проверял. У кого-нибудь есть идеи как отловить ту ошибку??

Comment: бесплатным хостингом не пользовался, но рискну предположить, что стоит ограничение на количество отправляемых писем в единицу времени.

Answer (score -3):

if($res) echo "OK"; else echo "Sorry..";

По моему ошибка в условии! 
Даже при твоем раскладе это должно было выглядеть так:
if($res){
echo "ok";
}else{
echo "Sorry";
}

И где блин само условие то?
Функция mail()  должна вернуть true если все пучком, false  если отправка не удастся 
Тоесть условие твоё должно выглядеть так

if($res == true){
echo "ok";
}else{
echo "Sorry";
}

Comment: @icedev if(true == true) return true 

замечательные условия у вас =) 

функция mail возвращает логическое значение, которое необходимо оператору if. Сравнение результата с true бессмысленно.

Comment: Жесть!

Ковычки нужны не всегда, смысл городить их куда только можно.

Comment: Халк злой!!!  
Готов убить каждого кто напишет `if($res == true)`... Стереть с лица Земли этих быдло-кодеров... >__<