# При отправке письма не совпадает кодировка

Tags: кодировка, php

При отправке письма не совпадает кодировка, хотя везде на сайте через `header()` указана (догадываюсь, что связи может и не быть между ними), в письме html нет, просто русский текст. Что делать? Через `headers` в параметрах отправки? Если да, то как?
Спасибо.

Comment: [www.google.com/search?q=php+mail()+русский+текст][1]

  [1]: http://www.google.com/search?q=php+mail()+русский+текст

Comment: Обязательно использовать mail() напрямую или допускается удобная обертка? Если второе, то можно воспользоваться готовым высокоуровневым классом [PHPMailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тут тоже есть поиск

[Здесь есть пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/87596/%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%B2-%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B5)

Comment: Сорри.спасибо)

Comment: на закрытие вопроса надо комментить? тогда, админы, можете закрывать) иначе извините, но я не нашёл как самому)

Comment: Если есть принятый ответ, то вопрос считается "закрытым". Даже после закрытия вопроса можно отвечать или комментить...